# SP 2013 Document Library Alerts

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, alert

I've created a few doc libraries on a site, and would like one question answered before I go any further with it:  I created an ALERT notification for each of the libraries, and put the email addresses of the group of people who should receive the notifications.  NOTE:  I was not one of the people in these groups set to receive these notifications.   When I went back to edit these notifications, I could not see them.  Could this perhaps be because I did not set myself as one of the recipients? Or are they lost, and I need to re-create them?

Comment: Yes, you can only view the alerts which set receiver as yourself through manage my alert.

Answer (score 2):

You can only view or cancel alerts:

Settings > Site Settings > Site Administration > User Alerts

[Manage, view, or delete SharePoint alerts](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/manage-view-or-delete-sharepoint-alerts-99dfb19c-9a90-4a8c-aba1-aa8c8afb0de2#ID0EAADAAA=Online)